# Silverstripe function intercept

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

Is anyone able to tell me how to write a function that can intercept the publish command on silverstripe? I want to implement a system where whenever a page change is about to occur, a HTTP call to another system is sent, that will inform the administrator that a page has been changed. I want the system to wait a few minutes then, giving the administrator time to remove the change if it wasn't authorised.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this? http://www.silverstripe.org/cms-workflow-module/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's various event hooks in the `SiteTree` class which you can use for this purpose.

```
class MySiteTreeExtension extends DataExtension {
    function onAfterPublish() {
        $this->notifyMyAdmin(sprintf('Page "%s" has been published', $this->owner->Title));
    }
}
```

Apply the extension with the following addition to your `mysite/_config.php`:

```
Object::add_extension('SiteTree', 'MySiteTreeExtension');
```

You'll obviously need to implement the `notifyMyAdmin()` method to make that HTTP call.
In general, I would advise against doing synchronous HTTP calls on user actions though,
since they make your system dependent on the availability of another one. Consider using something like the [messagequeue](http://www.silverstripe.org/message-queue-module/) module instead. In terms of "wait a few minutes with publication": Its not possible to "veto" publications through the extension system.
You could overwrite `SiteTree->doPublish()` in your subclass for this purpose, but it would still be a bit of a weird UI pattern for the user. Workflow module plus "Request Publication" plus some cron job to auto-approve them would be more straightforward.

Comment: Ingo,
Thanks for the heads up. I'm not sure how to do the "Request Publication" that you are suggesting. The onAfterPublish is useful, thanks.